# Using ZipPackage in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

so I learned about the `System.IO.Packaging.ZipPackage` in .NET. I am trying to use it to extract a thumbnail that is located in word documents if you 'Save as Thumbnail', the general advice seems to be to use a third-part library instead, but does anyone perhaps know how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know you are only working with .docx files, you can read the thumbnail, if the document has one, using this code:

```
ZipPackage zip = ZipPackage.Open(@"C:\Test Documents\thumbnail.docx") as ZipPackage;
var part = zip.GetPart(new Uri("/docProps/thumbnail.emf", UriKind.Relative));
if (part != null)
{
    Image i = Image.FromStream(part.GetStream());
    pictureBox1.Image = i;
}
```

Comment: heh, that works but with some weird side effects, the background turns black and the text turns red, any idea why?

Comment: On mine it appeared that the background was transparent.  Save it as an .emf file to your local disk and then open it in windows viewer.  If you are saving it as a jpg or something like that it might be trying to guess the correct colors.